# How do I repeat a single value of a list using python

Tags: python, list, coordinates, repeat

I have a list of over 2000 xyz coordinates and i just want to repeat a single value right after the occurance of the first

```
[[-2000, 379, -1817]]
```

I want this

```
[[-2000 379 -1817],
[-2000 379 -1817]]
```

But I only repeat this value no other value in the list.

The index of this value is 716

Comment: that second thing isn't a valid python data structure.  Did you mean to have a comma in between sub-lists (and elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do (if `l` is your list)

```
l[716:716] = [l[716]]
```

Comment: @RemcoGerlich it works, but could you explain why? :) How would you 'read' this?

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the list by an integer.

```
[[-2000, 379, -1817]]*2
```

Example:

```
 [[-2000, 379, -1817]]*2
 #output: [[-2000, 379, -1817], 
 #         [-2000, 379, -1817]]
```

Note:
If you want to change a value, lets say you have the following:

```
a = [[-2000, 379, -1817]]
a = a*2
print a
#output: [[-2000, 379, -1817], [-2000, 379, -1817]]

a[0][0] = 10
print a 
#output  [[10, 379, -1817], [10, 379, -1817]]
```

This will create a copy only, so if you modify one the other will get modified.

Now if you want to modify each, without creating a copy you could do the following:

```
a = [[10, 379, -1817] for i in range(2)]
#output: [[10, 379, -1817], 
#         [10, 379, -1817]]

a[0][0] = 3
print a
#output: [[3, 379, -1817],
#         [10, 379, -1817]]
```

Comment: You should mention what doing something like `x[0][0] = 4` will do in this case.

Comment: This creates two copies of the same object, i.e modifying one in-place is going to affect the other one as well. Better use: `[[-2000, 379, -1817] for _ in xrange(2)]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like `l[:717]+l[716:]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use slicing. For example here you want to repeat the item at index 1:

```
>>> lis = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> lis[1:2] = [lis[1][:] for _ in xrange(2)]
>>> lis
[[1], [2], [2], [3]]
>>> lis[1] is lis[2]  #both lists are different objects.
False
```

You can use slicing to insert as many items as possible:

```
>>> lis = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> lis[1:2] = [lis[1][:] for _ in xrange(4)]
>>> lis
[[1], [2], [2], [2], [2], [3]]
```

`[:]` returns a shallow copy of the list. So, modifying `lis[1]` will not affect `lis[2]`, but if `lis[1]` contains mutable objects too then use `copy.deepcopy`.

In case if you want the new item(s) to be just a reference(s) to the original object then drop the `[:]`.

---

Secondly if it's just one item then you can also use **`list.insert`**:

```
>>> lis = [[1], [2], [3]]
>>> lis.insert(2, lis[1][:])
>>> lis
[[1], [2], [2], [3]]
```

Help on `list.insert`:

```
insert(...)
    L.insert(index, object) -- insert object before index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting an element in a list, do something like so:

First, create a test list:

```
>>> li=[list(t) for t in zip(*[iter(range(27))]*3)]
>>> li
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]]
```

Then you can insert a duplicate element like so:

```
>>> li.insert(2,li[2])
>>> li
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26]]
                        ^^^^^^^
```